# Does WebRTC allow one-to-many (multicast) connections?

Tags: webrtc

I've read a lot about WebRTC, but there's one question that still remains. I hope you can help me with that:

Does WebRTC allow me to create a one-to-many connection? I don't mean "being able to have multiple connections to different computers", I really talk about having one connection that multicasts its data to multiple endpoints without the need to "upload" the data once for each endpoint. Will it be possible to send one single package to the web, that, when it reaches the web, magically splits itself into multiple packages with different targets?

I hope you get what I'm looking for :)

Until now, I've only seen one-to-one connections, or solutions that have one connection to a central server that does the multicast for them (which usually results in twice the ping).

But to me, one-to-one connections don't seem to be really useful (due to low upload-bandwith of clients), and solutions with a central server are also possible without WebRTC (using WebSockets), so the only real use case for WebRTC would be one-to-many connections.

So.. is this something that will be possible in the future? Or is it already possible today?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three things:

1. IP multicast in the Internet is not possible at the moment (multicast addresses are not routed by ISPs)
2. WebRTC fits many use cases beyond one-to-many communication, just have a look at this document: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-use-cases-and-requirements-06
3. WebRTC connections between browsers are always encrypted (using SRTP for A/V data and DTLS for generic data) and the encryption parameters (session keys etc.) are negotiated for every connection separately. How would you do that in a multicast environment (think of it as a distribution tree)?

So no, WebRTC cannot be used with IP multicast.

Comment: Point 1. is not entirely true. ISPs provide media such as video or audio streams via multicast.

Comment: You're right, ISPs like Deutsche Telekom use Multicast to distribute their IPTV content. Those multicast networks are closed, though, and cannot be used for content dissemination by any user except Deutsche Telekom.

Comment: @Makkes: Can we make multicase(one to many) video application with different devices compatibility using webRTC? (iPhone, iPad & Desktop) . Because I read a lot of WebRTC, ultimately I get confused. Please advice.

Comment: @Makkes: Please go through this page. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-use-cases-and-requirements-06#section-4.2.10  Is multicast or multiparty possible?

Comment: "the browser of each participant sends and receives streams to and from all other session participants". So no, Multicast is not possible; yes, Multipary is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would answer "It **doesn't for now**", because as a programmer, I can tell you, that there are number of ways browser devs to make it work if we (users) insist on it's importance. 
But how ? 
Since there's encryption, they could allow **sharing** of the session's encryption keys to the group of 'registered' (multicast) users. 
But how ? Well, Web was **created** for sharing.
 The most obvious way is through web server mediation and JS WebRTC API function (to load the user keys). Since multicast is most often used for efficient video distribution, you have a RTP/SRTP video server.  The web server can coexist at the same machine. If they decide to extend it to web browsers - then just the "server" role can be done by the Web browser who created the multicast stream (the sender). The clients need to know who is it.

Again: In December 2013, this is still not possible. And multicasts are allowed on the Internet only in:

- some experimental WAN nets
- some internet+video ISP nets
- LANs (when enabled at switch level, cheap switches transmit it to all ports). But you can be an ISP, researcher or LAN user, so it's necessary.

Comment: Checking in a decade later, is this still the current situation?